# TextField value change when button is clicked

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, textfield

I am a beginning programmer creating a soccer application to simulate the group stage of a tournament. However, I've come across a problem that I can't handle. I have created a screen that has buttons at the top to change groups, yet when I change a group, the ScoreInput field (which is an OutlinedTextField) has the values from the previous group, and I would like the values to be the initial values, which is 0:0. I realize that this is still the same TextField, and I am only changing the teams displayed next to it, yet I don't know how to solve this problem (creating 6 separate screens that look the same also doesn't seem like a good idea to me). I also realize that the application should not contain so much logic on the UI layer, although I would like to take care of the optimization at a later stage.
I hope someone can help me and thank you very much in advance for your help.

Moreover, it needs to keep the option that the user can not edit the approved result in the same group, only after changing the group for further stages of the application

My Screen code:

```
@Composable
fun GroupStageScreen(viewModel: EuroViewModel) {
    val groups = listOf("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")
    val (matchResult, setMatchResult) = remember { mutableStateOf(MutableList(6) { EuroMatchResult(0, 0) })  }
    val groupData by viewModel.groupData.collectAsState(emptyList())
    val (selectedGroup, setSelectedGroup) = remember { mutableStateOf(groups[0]) }

    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        color = background_color
    ) {
        Column(
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            // Buttons for changing groups
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(5.dp)
                    .padding(top = 10.dp),
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.Top,
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
            ) {
                groups.forEach { groupInfo ->
                    Button(
                        onClick = {
                            setSelectedGroup(groupInfo)
                                  },
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(2.dp),
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(15.dp),
                        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                            backgroundColor = Color.Gray,
                            contentColor = Color.White
                        )
                    ) {
                        Text(text = groupInfo)
                    }
                }
            }
            val selectedGroupData = groupData.find { it.group == selectedGroup }
            selectedGroupData?.let {groupInfo ->
            // Group Table
            Text(
                text = "Group ${groupInfo.group}",
                color = Color.White,
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.h4,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center
            )
            Surface(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(7.dp)
                    .padding(top = 10.dp),
                color = Color.Gray,
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp),
                border = BorderStroke(2.dp, Color.Gray),
                elevation = 10.dp
            ) {
                    TeamTable(groupInfo.teams)
            }
            // Fields to fill the results
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
            Text(
                text = "Enter the match results: ",
                color = Color.White,
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.h6
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))

            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
                    .padding(bottom = 30.dp)
            ) {
                for (i in 0 until groupInfo.teams.size - 1) {
                    for (j in i + 1 until groupInfo.teams.size) {
                        val teamA = groupInfo.teams[i]
                        val teamB = groupInfo.teams[j]
                        val result = matchResult[i * 2 + j - (i * 1)]

                        MatchResultInput(
                            teamA = teamA.shortName,
                            teamB = teamB.shortName,
                            matchResult = result,
                            onResultChanged = { newResult ->
                                val updatedMatchResult = matchResult.toMutableList()
                                updatedMatchResult[i * 2 + j - (i + 1)] = newResult
                                setMatchResult(updatedMatchResult)

                                if (newResult.scoreA > newResult.scoreB) {
                                    teamA.matchesPlayed++
                                    teamA.matchesWon++
                                    teamA.points += 3
                                    teamB.matchesPlayed++
                                    teamB.matchesLost++
                                } else if (newResult.scoreA < newResult.scoreB) {
                                    teamA.matchesPlayed++
                                    teamA.matchesLost++
                                    teamB.matchesPlayed++
                                    teamB.matchesWon++
                                    teamB.points += 3
                                } else {
                                    // It's a draw
                                    teamA.matchesPlayed++
                                    teamA.matchesDrawn++
                                    teamA.points++
                                    teamB.matchesPlayed++
                                    teamB.matchesDrawn++
                                    teamB.points++
                                }
                            })
                    }
                }
            }
            }
        }
    }
}
@Composable
fun MatchResultInput(
    teamA: String,
    teamB: String,
    matchResult: EuroMatchResult,
    onResultChanged: (EuroMatchResult) -> Unit) {

    val scoreA = remember { mutableStateOf(matchResult.scoreA.toString()) }
    val scoreB = remember { mutableStateOf(matchResult.scoreB.toString()) }
    val showPredictions = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val buttonEnabled = remember { mutableStateOf(true) }


    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(start = 7.dp, end = 7.dp, top = 20.dp),
        color = Color.Gray,
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 40.dp, topEnd = 40.dp), //30
        border = BorderStroke(3.dp, Color.White),
        elevation = 10.dp
    ) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(4.dp)
                .padding(start = 15.dp, end = 15.dp, bottom = 5.dp),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {
            Column(
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(end = 8.dp)
            ) {
                Image(
                    painterResource(id = R.drawable.flag_poland),
                    contentDescription = null,
                    modifier = Modifier.size(70.dp) //70
                )
                Text(
                    text = teamA,
                    fontSize = 19.sp
                )
            }
            ScoreInput(
                scoreState = scoreA,
                onAction = KeyboardActions { FocusRequester.Default.requestFocus() },
                enabled = true,
                onScoreChanged = {newScore ->
                    scoreA.value = newScore
                }
            )
            Column(
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = ":",
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 40.dp,bottom = 12.dp),
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center)
                Button(
                    onClick = {
                              onResultChanged(EuroMatchResult(scoreA.value.toIntOrNull() ?: 0, scoreB.value.toIntOrNull() ?: 0))
                              showPredictions.value = true
                              buttonEnabled.value = false
                              },
                    modifier = Modifier.size(34.dp),
                    shape = CircleShape,
                    colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(backgroundColor = green_check, contentColor = Color.White, disabledBackgroundColor = little_green_check),
                    enabled = buttonEnabled.value) {
                    Text(text = "✓", fontSize = 12.sp, textAlign = TextAlign.Center, fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)
                }
            }

            ScoreInput(scoreState = scoreB,
                onScoreChanged = { newScore ->
                    scoreB.value = newScore
                })
            Column(
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 8.dp)
            ) {

                Image(
                    painterResource(id = R.drawable.flag_germany),
                    contentDescription = null,
                    modifier = Modifier.size(70.dp)
                )
                Text(
                    text = teamB,
                    fontSize = 19.sp
                )
            }
        }
    }
    Surface(modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 7.dp, end = 7.dp),
        color = Color.White,
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(bottomStart = 40.dp, bottomEnd = 40.dp), //30
        elevation = 10.dp) {
        Row(modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(top = 5.dp, bottom = 5.dp), verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically, horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center) {
        if (!showPredictions.value){
        Text(
            text = "Confirm the result to see other players predictions",
            modifier = Modifier.padding(7.dp),
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center)
        } else {

                Text(text = "33%", modifier = Modifier.weight(1f), textAlign = TextAlign.Center, fontSize = 20.sp, fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)
                Text(text = "34%", modifier = Modifier.weight(1f), textAlign = TextAlign.Center, fontSize = 20.sp, fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)
                Text(text = "33%", modifier = Modifier.weight(1f), textAlign = TextAlign.Center, fontSize = 20.sp, fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)
            }
        }
    }
}
@Composable
fun TeamTable(teams: List<Team>) {
    val sortedTeams = teams.sortedByDescending { it.points }

    Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(3.dp)) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {
            val headerTitles = listOf("M", "W", "D", "L", "Pts")
            Text(
                "Country",
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                modifier = Modifier.width(150.dp)
            )
            headerTitles.forEach { titles ->
                Text(
                    text = titles,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                    modifier = Modifier.width(50.dp)
                )
            }
        }

        sortedTeams.forEachIndexed { index, team ->
            Surface(color = Color.White) {
                Row(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                ) {
                    Image(
                        painterResource(id = R.drawable.flag_poland),
                        contentDescription = null,
                        modifier = Modifier.size(30.dp)
                    )
                    Text(
                        team.name,
                        textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .width(120.dp)
                            .padding(start = 10.dp)
                    )
                    listOf(
                        team.matchesPlayed,
                        team.matchesWon,
                        team.matchesDrawn,
                        team.matchesLost,
                        team.points).forEach { value ->
                        Text(
                            text = value.toString(),
                            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                            modifier = Modifier.width(50.dp)
                        )
                    }
                }
                Divider(thickness = 2.dp)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
data class EuroMatchResult(
    val scoreA: Int, val scoreB: Int
)

data class GroupData(
    val group: String,
    val teams: List<Team>
)

data class Team(
    val name: String,
    val shortName: String,
    var matchesPlayed: Int = 0,
    var matchesWon: Int = 0,
    var matchesDrawn: Int = 0,
    var matchesLost: Int = 0,
    var points: Int = 0,
)
```

Comment: Do you mean that every time the button with the "✓" is clicked the values of scoreA and scoreB should reset to 0 and 0?

Comment: @vasberc not exactly. I would like to reset the scores to 0:0 in TextFields after changing the group (one of those 6 buttons at the top). Now, when I change the group to, for example, B, the first match is already completed with a score of 1:2 from the previous group.

below link how it looks like to make it easier to understand:
https://i.imgur.com/wVU28v0.png
PS. Please don't pay attention to the flags because this is a alpha version of the screen :D

Comment: I think I got It, but probably you will need a way to retrieve the scores when you have already pressed the confirm result, so with one variable "matchResult" for all the groups maybe its difficult, you should think the possibility either to have for each group it's own viewModel and have the state of the group there or to create a different variable "matchResult" for each group inside the GroupStageScreen and pass the right one the MatchResultInput by checking the group.

Comment: @vasberc yes, you are right thank you very much but still the TextField into which I enter the score of the team, after changing the group is completed with the score of the previous group. Is it possible that after clicking the group change button this TextField will have a value of 0?

Comment: To keep your code as it is you can make these small changes:
1. define a list of matchResult for each group with default values 0:0 like you already do. 
2. under the selectedGroup define a list called currentGroupMatchResult and assign to it the right matchResult  list by cheking the  selectedGroup value.
3. probably because in the tab click you change the selected group the recomposition will calculate and the currentGroupMatchResult.
4. if not inside the onclick of the group tab also change the currentGroupMatchResult.

Comment: @vasberc thank you so much for your help and your time. What I meant, was that after changing the group, the textField into which the team score is entered should return to the value 0. I handled this myself - I did it by passing selectedGroup and lambda setSelectedGroup from GroupStageScreen to MatchResultInput, and then reacting here to the change of selectedGroup with DisposableEffect. Greetings to you and best wishes.

Answer (score 0):

(I hope I got your question right.)

The behaviour I guess you expect is that when the value of `matchResult` changes in `MatchResultInput`, your text fields will update with the new value. However, that is not the case. `State` objects persist across recomposition regardless of what triggered it, including the change of a parameter of the composable.

There are 2 ways you can make the text input change

1. The "correct one" would be to not use those 2 state objects. Instead just pass to `MatchResultInput` two functions `updateScoreA` and `updateScoreB` and *hoist* the state to the parent component. Now you can directly use the value of `matchResult` as argument for the text input and whenever the parent component updates it your text input should update asa well
2. The quicker solution, just add a LaunchedEffect with dependency to `matchResult.scoreA` to update the state for score A when that changes and another one for scoreB